# Event handler for loop with dynamic jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, click

What I want is to click on `#bt-1` and change the color of `#target-1`, click on `#bt-2` and change the color of `#target-2`...
I started writing a particular click event handler for each `#bt-n` / `#target-n` but as the site got bigger I thought about using a loop. My approach was using a for loop with variables in jQuery selectors. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var total = $('.target').length;
  for(n=1; n<=total; n++) {
    var num = String(n);
    $('#bt-'+num).on('click', function() {
      $('#target-'+num).toggleClass('yellow');
    });
  }
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.button, .target {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.button {
  background: gray;
}
#target-1 {
  background: red;
}
#target-2 {
  background: green;
}
#target-3 {
  background: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-1" class="button">
    <h1>Button 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-1" class="target">
    <h1>Target 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-2" class="button">
    <h1>Button 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-2" class="target">
    <h1>Target 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-3" class="button">
    <h1>Button 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-3" class="target">
    <h1>Target 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why it only targets the last `#target-n` as the loop seems to be working on `#bt-n`. I also thought about using an array but can't figure out how to implement it.

I managed to make it work using `$(this).siblings('.target')...` which do not require the for loop and ids but a parent element for each `.button` / `.target`, in this case `.wrapper` [Code Here](http://codepen.io/guizo/pen/VmOZqG). Although this was a good solution, I would like to understand what I did wrong and how to properly implement a loop to achieve this without using the parent `.wrapper`. Thank you.

Comment: instead of `'bt-'+num` i think you can use `'bt-'+n`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091765/assign-click-handlers-in-for-loop)

Comment: use `$(this).next().toggleClass('yellow')`

Comment: @RandomDeveloper At first I was using bt+n. If I use `'#bt-'+n` / `'#target'+n` on this snippet nothing happens while using `'#bt-'+num` / `'#target'+num` at least the the last object changes color. Here is where it gets strange: This works: 
`$('#bt-'+n).on('click', function() { $(this).toggleClass('yellow'); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that only the last item gets affected is because the loop has completed before any event fires. Therefore `n` holds the last value in the loop. To fix this you need to use a closure:

```
for (n = 1; n <= total; n++) {
  (function(n) {
    $('#bt-' + n).on('click', function() {
      $('#target-' + n).toggleClass('yellow');
    });
  })(n);
}
```

That said, a much better approach would be avoid the loop and to use DOM traversal to find the `.target` related to the clicked `.button`, like this:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.target').toggleClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.button,
.target {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.button {
  background: gray;
}
#target-1 {
  background: red;
}
#target-2 {
  background: green;
}
#target-3 {
  background: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-1" class="button">
    <h1>Button 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-1" class="target">
    <h1>Target 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-2" class="button">
    <h1>Button 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-2" class="target">
    <h1>Target 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="bt-3" class="button">
    <h1>Button 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="target-3" class="target">
    <h1>Target 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that `num` was holding only the last value but it is strange because the click event fires if I click `#bt-1`, `#bt-2` or `#bt-3`. So somehow not only the last valye is being passed at this line which does not happen in the next line for the `'#target'+num`.

Comment: Using `next()` sure is a better solution that using `siblings()` as I did. Thank you.

Comment: @guizo the event is attached to the correct elements, because the `num` is holds the correct value when finding those elements. The event handler itself attached to the elements isn't used until later, after the loop runs, hence `num` always has the final value.

Answer (score 0):

It is unwise to register a lot of event handlers. You can bind one event handler and perform action for given specific idx read from element id, eg:

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
    if (!event.target.id.match(/^bt-\d+/)) {
        return; //id of clicked element does not match bt-{number}
    }

    var idx = event.target.id.replace('bt-', ''); //remove prefix "bt-" and leave only numeric postfix

    $('#target-' + idx).toggleClass('yellow');
});
```

Explanation:

When you bind `click` on `body` element You are getting access to all `click` events from child elements that not cancelled passing that event up. Element that has been clicked in saved inside `event.target` and it has property `id` in `event.target.id`.

On this id property I call match function with regular expression - it will match string which starts `^` from `bt-` and have any number `\d` at least one one `+` .

```
if (!event.target.id.match(/^bt-\d+/)) {
    return; //id of clicked element does not match bt-{number}
}
```

There is negation of this statement, so If this `id` is not in format `bt-someNumber` it will not go further.

```
var idx = event.target.id.replace('bt-', '');
```

Than takes `id` and replaces `bt-` part in it with empty string `''`

```
$('#target-' + idx).toggleClass('yellow');
```

Finally You are toggling class on element with same number as button but with different prefix `target-` instead of `bt-`.

Happy hacking!

Comment: It works but I didn`t understood what is happening in the if statment.

Comment: I have added explanation of this process in post ;)